# Pandas to_latex Encoding Issues

Tags: input-encodings, python

I'm using python and pandas to run a script and generate a latex table from a couple files I have.

I'm doing this by importing a java .properties file (encoded in ISO-8859-1 with special unicode-escaped characters) which I'm calling dictionaryFileName that contains paired values for translations and mapping them to entries in a csv file (permissionFileName) that contains the permissions I want to translate. For that, i'm using pandas to import the csv and manage it. Lastly, i'm exporting them straight to latex table format with `pandas.series.to_latex()`.

Here's the python script I'm using:

```
with open(dictionaryFileName, encoding="ISO-8859-1") as d:
    commands = dict(line.split('=', 1) for line in d)

commands = {key:value.encode().decode('unicode-escape') 
            for key, value in commands.items()}

data = pd.read_csv(permissionFileName)

data.module_name = (data.module_name
                       .map(commands)
                       .replace('\\n', '', regex=True))
grouped_data = data.groupby(['module_name', 'group_name','permission_name']).count()

with open("../apendices/permission-table.tex", "w+") as pt:
    pt.write(grouped_data.to_latex(multirow=True, longtable=True, escape=False, encoding="UTF-8"))
```

I'm exporting it as UTF-8, since that's the encoding I'm using in latex. Then, I import the table in latex with `\input(apendices/permission-table.tex)` using the code below:

main.tex

```latex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, brazil]{babel}
\begin{document}
\input{apendices/permission-table.tex}
\end{document}
```

permission-table.tex:

```latex
\begin{longtable}{lll}
\multirow{14}{*}{Avaliação} & Página de autoavaliação & Ler \\
\end{longtable}
```

The input files look like this:

dictionaryFile

```
EVALUATION=Avalia\u00e7\u00e3o
```

permissionFile

```
ACTION_PLAN,GROUP_ANALYTICAL_ACTION_PLAN_REPORT,READ
```

However, when I try to compile the latex file, every special character (such as the one from the example above with `'ç'` and `'ã'`) throws the error message "Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.".

Copying the contents of the file, pasting it in another file and importing this new one instead solves the problem though. If I open the file in any text reader, all characters are as they're supposed to be.

If I use `\useRawInputEncoding` the special characters just go missing.

I wanted this to work straight out of python because I'll need to update this table a lot and it'd be easier if I didn't have to manually copy a file into another to make it work.

Comment: Which operating system do you use? If it is Linux then it would be interesting to see the output of `file permission-table.tex` (which tells you the encoding, among other things), and, when you copy the contents to the file that does work properly, if the encoding reported by `file` is different for that other file.

Comment: @Marijn I'm using Windows, so the encoding is also a property of the file? That's good to know. I'll take a look into how to find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up finding out thanks to the answer from @Marijn.

I actually needed to set the encoding to the output file from python, not to the dataframe from pandas.

So, changing the open file as write to the following code mate it work:

```
with open("../apendices/permission-table.tex", "w+", encoding="UTF-8") as pt:
    pt.write(grouped_data.to_latex(multirow=True, longtable=True, escape=False, encoding="UTF-8"))
```